# The mapcontrol zooms undesirable when setting either Heading, Center or Style. (since Creator update)

Tags: windows-10, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm working on a UWP project which uses the MapControl.
After updating to the Creator Update for Windows 10, the mapcontrol behaves in unexpected and undesired ways:
I update the heading and center almost constantly, but this now causes the zoomlevel to change slowly over time.
And when I change the mapstyle, it zooms out by a lot. (But this seemingly only when I update either/both the heading and/or center)

I have no idea why this is happening or how to avoid it.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that is currently being investigated.
As a workaround, rather than independently setting zoom and center, try using the SetScene API.
like this:
TrySetSceneAsync(MapScene.CreateFromLocationAndRadius(newCenter, newRadius, heading, pitch), MapAnimationKind.Linear);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapControl_TrySetSceneAsync_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapScene_

Comment: Ah ok, so it's a known bug. Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that workaround does not solve the fact that the zoom changes when setting the mapstyle. Also, I would like to keep the mousescroll (zoom in/out) functionality, but I would lose that if I use TrySetSceneAsync() each frame, as it would change the zoom as well.

Comment: There are different variants of TrySetScene that you can choose what to set. You can also try the TryPanToAsync API.